# Issue with JSONMANAGED Reference

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa

I am trying to use json manged reference in one of my entity class.that has a manytoone relationship with another entity that has a composite primary key.

In class A I have

```
 /**
     * @return the classB
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SEC_ID", referencedColumnName = "PT_ID", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    public classB getClassB() {
        return classB;
    }
```

ClassB

```
/**
 * @return the pxxId
 */
@EmbeddedId
public PxxId getPxxId() {
    return pxxId;
}
```

Embedded Id

```
@Embeddable
public class PxxId implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7080557675086058087L;
    private Long taId;
    private Long maId;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Column(name = "PT_ID", nullable = false, length = 20)
    public Long getTaId() {
        return tabId;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setTaId(Long id) {
        this.taId = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the maId
     */
    @Column(name = "MA_ID", length = 20, nullable = false)
    public Long getMaId() {
        return maId;
    }

    /**
     * @param mId
     *            the maId to set
     */
    public void setMaId(Long maId) {
        this.maId = maId;
    }
}
```

I tried the above but getting error like

```
... 41 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(PT_ID) of com.citi.aml.npa.domain.ClassA.classB referencing com.citi.aml.npa.domain.ClassB not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1557)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1478)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1781)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    ... 48 more
```

Can someone kindly help me.

Comment: Add `@EmbeddedId` in `PT_ID` column too.

Comment: why will that work PT_ID is itself not an embeddedId.

Comment: The key of B is PxxId so you also have to reference both columns in your manyToOne mapping

Comment: @SimonMartinelli in classA i have only one column of the two embedded id column of classB. the requirement is like that

Comment: JSON annotations are bugger all to do with the problem (so remove that distraction from your question - JSON is a totally separate process, this is Hibernate JPA objecting to the mapping), your JPA mapping is the problem. If a `ClassA` has a relation to `ClassB` and `ClassB` has 2 PK fields (columns) then the FK across to `ClassB` has 2 columns. It cannot have 1!